# Voltage/Ampere switch

Tags: dc, 12v, over-voltage-protection

I have 12 V DC solar pump. Since solar gives a variable power, I need an automatic solution to switch on the pump when the output reaches 12 V/1 A. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hypothetically yes, but can’t you just use the normal solar cell -> MPPT -> pump and let the pump vary with the solar radiation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd want what winny says, especially because you need some protection circuitry, anyways - you can't burn the pump when sun is too strong, nor does the panel like back-EMF from an electric motor.

Comment: Will MPPT protect the pump and the cell? It's small setup for fountain. MPPt is costly. Right now it's like Solar => PWM => pump .

Comment: By cell, do you mean solar cell? A solar cell probably needs no protection in this setup. What’s the problem with the PWM setup you have now?

Comment: Right it's working. But i think it would be better to have a protection. Also is there any difference between MPPT/PWM ?

Comment: MPPT is PWM with “brains” to adjust the output current to maximize the power output at every given moment with varying solar irradiation. What do you plan to protect against? I’m sensing an XY problem.

Comment: trick question: the output won't reach "1A" if not switched on. the >12v trigger part is no problem, just stack up 4 or 5 leds in series (or use a zener); when they light, the voltage is above 12v.